# Create react app error - "Module not found" on npm start

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am trying to start React project with create-react-app.
Got an error on **npm start**:

```
Failed to compile.

multi ./node_modules/react-scripts/config/polyfills.js ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js ./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'D:\' in 'D:\!!!DESKTOP\React-test\test-react'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: so you installed the create-react-app package using npm as globally

Comment: @Skif was your issue resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An exclamation mark is part of webpack loader syntax.
Remove exclamation sign from your directory path `D:\!!!DESKTOP\React-test\test-react` More info - [Webpack Loaders configuration](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#configuration)

Answer (score 6):

Please follow these steps:

1. Remove `package-lock.json` form the project's directory.
2. Then, run `npm install`.
3. And then, do `npm start` again.
4. If the issue persists do, `rm -rf node_modules` to remove the `node_modules` folder and start again from step 1.

Hope this helps. :)